# Spring is not saving data in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

`spring` is not saving data in mysql.

The table is created, but after creation the lines are nulls.

```
//class
@Component
public class DataInicializr implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent arg0) {
        //Sempre vai rodar no inicio da aplicacao
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail("jaraujo@gmail.com");
        user.setNome("Jorge David");        
        userRepository.save(user);              
    }
}
```

Comment: Show error message.

Comment: show you main class

Comment: Hi, guys. Not exist error message, simply isn't saving.

Comment: Main Class                                                                                                         
  `                                                                                                           
 package com.projeto.principal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Projeto5Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Projeto5Application.class, args);
 }

}

`

Comment: @user3337096, did you find some solution for this issue ? i am facing same now !

Comment: Did you check `onApplicationEvent` is at least called? With a breakpoint on debug mode, or with a `System.out.println("whatever");`?